# Issue with decoding json array in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Okay now i am having a weird issue here, sometime back i learned how to encode and decode a json array properly here on stackoverflow but now i am having a weird issue on my godaddy server that i cannot comprehend, maybe i may have made i typo or something somewhere in code but i honestly cannot tell what is wrong here.  The code works okay on my localhost but not when i upload it too my godaddy server.

The code here is basically supposed to pass an id as a json to the php server which is then supposed to execute a query using the id as a parameter.

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script text="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#download').click(function(e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            var tid = $('#id').val().trim();

            var data = {
                ID:tid
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xxxxx-xxxxxxx.php",
                data: {
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['data']))
    {   
        $Data = $_POST["data"];
        $arr = json_decode($Data);
        $id = $arr->ID;

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("update ********** set ******** = ******** + 1 where id=:id");
        $sql->bindValue("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();

        unset($_POST['data']);
    }
?>
```

Now i checked if the value was being sent to the server using my browser console and it was.  I also checked if the $_POST['data'] on the server contained any data using var_dump and it did in fact have the data i wanted.

Comment: Do you have access to an error log on your server? That would be a good start. It may be that a function you are using is not available on the version of PHP your server has. Especially with a GoDaddy shared hosting plan the version of PHP could be out of date.

Comment: You don't need to encode with json.stringify - it's already a javascript object. You could then remove the json_decode from your PHP file.

Comment: just send the data as is.  dont use stringify.  you'll get the data in your post array directly.

Comment: @hamobi Then how do i decode it, because it says json_decode expects parameter 1 to be string.

Comment: @Michael Benjamin i tried that and it didn't work

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here, it works well on my localhost but not on my godaddy server.

Comment: dont use json_decode.  just use $_POST['data']

Comment: Post the dump of $_POST[data]

Answer (score 0):

in the ajax set the content type to `contentType: "application/json",`

so:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxxx-xxxxxxx.php",
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });
```

and in the php use:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: I'm curious, what does this line "$json = file_get_contents('php://input');" mean and do?

Comment: when sending raw Json (as it seems you wish to do) you cannot rely on the $_POST array being populated so you'll need to read from the file descriptor instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Yeah i tried your solution but it didn't work, maybe i'm doing it wrong but thankx anyway, i already got an answer, :)